# Sum of multiples of two numbers

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to find out the sum of multiples of two numbers using python.I have done it already. I just want to solve it using lambda functions.
Without lambda code

```
   def sumMultiples(num, limit):

    sum = 0
    for i in xrange(num, limit, num):
        sum += i
    return sum

def sum(limit):
    return (sumMultiples(3, limit) +
            sumMultiples(5, limit) -
            sumMultiples(15, limit))

print sum(1000)
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: What does "sum of multiples" mean?

Comment: Please make an attempt at solving this yourself. If you have already made an attempt but neglected to include your code, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33111338/edit) your question and include it. If you have not yet made an attempt, give this a shot yourself and come to us if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
a = input("enter first number\n")
b= input("enter second number\n")
limit=[]
limit.append(a)
limit.append(b)
natNo=range(1,1000)
xyz = []
for i in limit:
    xyz +=filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i==0, natNo)   
set = {}
map(set.__setitem__, xyz, [])
nums=set.keys()
print "the multiples of the given numbers are: "+str(nums)
c=reduce(lambda x, y:x+y, nums)
print "the sum of the multiples of the given numbers is "+str(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
limit = 1000
a=lambda num, limit: sum([i for i in xrange(num, limit, num)])
print a(3,limit)+a(5,limit)-a(15,limit)
```